# template tag inside object TextField

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I need custom template tag inside `model.TextField` value. Value from the object text field have something like `"lorem ipsum dolor {% mytag %}"` but "mytag" is not rendered as template tag. It is registered in the library as tag and loaded on the page and I have `{{ object.textfield|safe }}` filter. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Django's template engine can easily be used anywhere in your code you should be able to do something like this:

```
from django.template import Context, Template
rendered = Template("{% load your_tag_library %}",
    object.textfield).render(Context())
```

Rather than rendering the template from a file it renders it from a string like:

```
"{% load your_tag_library %}lorem ipsum dolor {% mytag %}"
```

The code can for instance be used in your view or as a method on your model. Note that the `Context` is empty, you might as well pass a dict with template variables to it.

Furthermore, to handle it directly in the template you could write a custom templatetag which does something similiar, basically a templatetag that parses strings for templatetags.