# Template tags in model text fields

Tags: django, templates, django-models, django-templates, django-views

How can I make Django templates render template tags contained in model TextField fields?

For example, having this content in a model field:

```
object.description = "We have all the links here: {% url 'list' %}"
```

It is displaying just the field content without processing the **url** tag, how can I process it?

(Before being marked as a duplicate, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11874325/1165509) doesn't answer it.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a custom template tag, I did the following.

```
# blog_tags.py
from django.template import Context, Template
from django import template

register = template.Library()


class RenderCustom(template.Node):

    @classmethod
    def handle_token(cls, parser, token):
        tokens = token.split_contents()

        field = tokens[1]

        return cls(parser.compile_filter(field))

    def __init__(self, field):
        self.field = field

    def render(self, context):
        render_field = self.field.resolve(context)

        render_template = Template(render_field)

        rendered = render_template.render(Context())

        return rendered


@register.tag
def render_this(parser, token):
    return RenderCustom.handle_token(parser, token)
```

on your template do like this:

```
# view_post.html
{% load blog_tags %}
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    {{ post.content }}
<hr>
    {% render_this post.title %}
```

It'll return something like this:

```
# The rendered page
Lol {% url 'admin:index' %}
The content
Lol /admin/
```