# How can I use a Django template variable in HTML in a model TextField?

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I want to generate external urls programatically instead of hard-coding them in HTML in case any one of them should change at some point

In my template I have this.

```
<p>
{{ article.text|safe }}
</p>
```

My Article class is this.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    teaser = models.TextField(default = "")
    text = models.TextField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image_name = models.CharField(default = "", max_length=100)
    published_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

My View class is this.

```
class Article_Page(TemplateView):
    model = Article
    template_name="articles/article.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Article_Page,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['article'] = Article.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
        context['external_urls'] = External_Urls()
        return context

class External_Urls(object):
    stack_overflow = 'https://stackoverflow.com'
```

And in my TextField in the model I have this.

```
<a href="{{ external_urls.stack_overflow }}>Stack Overflow</a>
```

That line of HTML gives a link to https://stackoverflow.com if I include it directly in the template, but if it is in the model TextField the link goes to 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/pk/{{ external_urls.stack_overflow }}'.

How can I escape template variables in TextField HTML?

Comment: You have to put quotes around attributes in HTML: `href="{{ external_urls.stack_overflow }}"`. Please fix that first, then update your question :)

Comment: It won't work either way template engine will render variable inside the quotes

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do here. Do you have django template code saved in your model's `text` field? If you want to insert the correct link, you have to do template rendering on the contents of the text field.

Comment: Is this what you want to do?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874325/template-tag-inside-object-textfield

Comment: @ArpitSolanki> sure it will. The problem is not with rendering, the problem is without the quotes you get invalid html. The browser will attempt giving it a meaning, but you cannot be sure how.

Comment: Correct @spectras I guess OP can use verbatim template tag of django but not sure how to inject inside a variable value

Comment: @spectras: Good point, I tried your suggestion and now the template variable name is added to the url, but still not the value (updated in the question).

Comment: Add your solution in an answer not in the question see [tour]

Comment: Why aren't you using DetailView? It handles automatically the matching pk from url with your Model.

Comment: @ShadowXsc Thanks! I didn't know about it, I'm a Django beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this:

```
class Article_Page(DetailView):
    model = Article
    template_name="articles/article.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Article_Page, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        d = {'external_urls':{'stackoverflow.com':'http://www.stackoverflow.com/'}}
        rendered = Template(self.object.text).render(Context(d))

        context['article'] = self.object
        context['article_text_rendered'] = rendered
        return context
```

Then in the HTML:

```
<p>
   {{ article_text_rendered }}
</p>
```

The key here is that the HTML from the TextField (i.e. article.text and page_object.text) can't use the same context as the page, so you have to render it first with its own context.

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
class Article_Page(TemplateView):
    model = Article
    template_name="articles/article.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Article_Page,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['article'] = Article.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
        context['external_urls'] = 'https://stackoverflow.com'
        return context
```

and in your template just put`{{external_urls}}`, if you want to create many urls you can use a list or a dictionary an example of a dictionary would be:

```
context['external_urls'] = ['url1':'https://stackoverflow.com', 'url2':'https://facebook.com']
```

and in your template:

```
{{external_urls.url1}} #return stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: I still have the same problem, that "{{external_urls.url1}}" when included in a TextField that is inserted into a django template, is treated as a string not as a template variable.

Comment: what do you men as a texfield, it worked for me, maybe replace the [] for {}

Comment: I mean TextField in the model that the object comes from, I have HTML in this TextField that I want to render. I solved it though, solution in original post.